# LaTeX Texmaker ERROR cannot find abc.bcf

Tags: texmaker

I have a basic tex file 'latextry.tex', which always throws the error
"cannot find ‘latextry.bcf‘!.
In its directory, there is no bcc file to be found. Isn't this generated automatically?
If I try pdflatex, the pdf is generated. But the error really confuses me and I would appreciate if someone has a solution to this.

the log file says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.20)  28 OCT 2022 15:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**latextry.tex
(./latextry.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
(./latextry.aux)
\openout1 = `latextry.aux'.
> 

>LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 9.
 [1
{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./late
xtry.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 459 strings out of 478268
 8560 string characters out of 5846346
 298226 words of memory out of 5000000
 18736 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 472899 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,6n,38p,154b,191s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
r10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
2.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.
pfb>
Output written on latextry.pdf (1 page, 46451 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: there is no error in the log-file. But it looks as if you are trying to call biber, but as your document doesn't use biblatex that doesn't make sense. Change the compilation method to use only pdflatex and not also other tools.

Comment: Thank you, now the Error doesn't show anymore! However, in the command configurations had I set Bib(la)tex to biber % - shouldn't I be able to perform BibTeX without error then?
Also: I have another file, which never threw the same error, while having all the same setting. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: don't mix biblatex, biber and bibtex. They are three different things. Call biber only if your document contains \usepackage{biblatex}, then it is needed and will also work.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my question, now I can do further research!